# eclipse egit cannot connect to remote repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, import

I am running Win7. I have installed egit plugin on Eclipse Juno. I am trying to import from a remote git repository but after some seconds I get this error:

**"ssh://user@host/repository_path:java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out:Connect
ssh://user@host/repository_path:java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out:Connect

Please check:

- Network conection settings
- Network connection->SS2 Eclipse preferences".**


I have already created a pair of public (2048 bit) - private key (which have been veryfied by the server administrtor as valid keys).

I have stored these keys in the *"SS2 home"* directory as it is specified in Eclipse preferences *(->general->network connections->ss2)*.

When this failed, I tried to load these keys manually from *key management* but I got the error ***"failed to load given file"***. I have even tried to remove the private key passphrase in order to load it to eclipse and change it back to the original via "key management", but, unfortunately, this has failed too.

Answer (score 0):

In the same screen SSH2 Preferences, did you add the newly generated key by clicking Add Private Key?